# Cannot change directory permission

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running an application over `php-fpm`, this is the project structure:

[image]

what I'm trying to do is chown the directories `src/writable` and `src/public` by the `www-data` user.

The `docker-compose` file have this content:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  php-fpm:
    container_name: boilerplate_app
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: boilerplate_nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${HOST}
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ${HOST}
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: ${EMAIL}
      
  database:
    container_name: boilerplate_db
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./docker/database
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PWD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PWD_ROOT}
    volumes:
      - ./docker/database/data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data.sql

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: boilerplate_phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8089:80
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=database
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PWD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PWD_ROOT}
    depends_on:
      - database
    
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: proxy
```

I'm running the following `Dockerfile` for `php-fpm`:

```
FROM php:8.0.2-fpm-alpine
WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN apk add icu-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl && docker-php-ext-install intl

RUN apk add --update libzip-dev curl-dev &&\
    docker-php-ext-install curl && \
    apk del gcc g++ &&\
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY docker/php-fpm/config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm
RUN npm install gulp-cli -g
RUN npm install

COPY src src/

RUN ls -l
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/writable
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/public

CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

the problem's that when this line is reached:

```
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/writable
```

I get:

> chown: /var/www/html/writable: No such file or directory

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did never copy or add files to `/var/www/html/`

Maybe you've chosen the wrong destination path in your copy command: `COPY src src/`

Please consider also that **the volume of your docker-compose file is only mounted if your container is running** and not while the image is building.
A volume can also overlay folder and files, which you've added in the `Dockerfile`, once the container is running.

You might want to create a helper script, which runs on start of the container and does chown the folders.
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint

Comment: Why you said that I never copied the file? I did `COPY src src/` which copied all the files in the `/var/www/html` workdir

Comment: I accidentally thought that ` src/` was an absolute path.

But does `COPY src src/` copy it to ` /var/www/html/src` instead of /var/www/html` and you try to chown `/var/www/html/writable` ?
Could you add a `RUN ls` before the `COPY`, to see which file exist there?

Comment: `ls` return this: `package-lock.json, src`

Comment: Than you copy your files to the wrong folder as mention above.
Try `COPY src .` instead `COPY src src/`.


Or you chown the wrong folder than you can try:
`RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/htm/src/writable` instead of `RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/writable`

Comment: yep, now I doesn't have any error but for some reason when I enter in the container and write `ls -l` I still see that chown command didn't worked, the two dirs are chowned by root user, am I missing something?

Comment: You did mount `./src` to `/var/www/html` in your docker-compose.
This does overlay the folder how I did mention above.

If `./src` is owned by root on the host. `/var/www/html` is owned by root in the container, too.

I do not understand, why you does add  `./src` in the Dockerfile, if you did also mount the folder in the docker-compose.

Comment: removing `volumes` work fine, but now when I browse my site I get "File not found" from nginx

Comment: May simple chown `.src` on your host, remove the `ADD`s and chwons in your `Dockerfile` and keep the volume in your docker-compose?

Comment: I would like to add this directive in the Dockerfile so I don't have to do this on each host. So the question is: how can I copy all the content of src in /var/www/html?

Comment: There are 2 option:
1 mount every file/ folder manuell. As example: `/src/index.html:/var/www/html/index.html:ro`.
2 or you mount them to a different folder and add a script, which does copy it to  `/var/www/html/`

Comment: Please consider also that your change in `/var/www/html/writable` get lost, if you do not mount it in a volume.